# Method not calling

Tags: java, class, methods

In first class file there is GUI created

```
public class TicTac extends JFrame {
TicTacEvent tictac = new TicTacEvent(this);
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton[][] boxes = new JButton[4][4];
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
JOptionPane win = new JOptionPane("Winner");
ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");

public TicTac() {
    super ("Tic Tac Toe");
    setSize (800,650);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(layout);
    int name = 0;
    String newname;

    GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(5, 4, 10, 10);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            name = name + 1;
            newname = Integer.toString(name);
            boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname);
            boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
            row1.add(boxes[x][y]);
        }
    }
    row1.add(blank1);
    row1.add(play);
    row1.add(blank2);
    row1.add(restart);
    add (row1);

    play.addActionListener(tictac);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            boxes[x][y].addActionListener(tictac);
        }
    }


    setVisible(true);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a restart button, however my method isn't calling

```
   Thread playing;
   Thread restarting;
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

   String command = event.getActionCommand();

   if (command.equals("Play")) {
    startPlaying();  
       }
          if (command.equals("Restart")){
   restart();
```

My Restart method isn't calling at all, I've tried just random setText's in the method alone and it still won't do that, I'm not sure why, there is no error. Another question I'll have later on though is fixing my restart method, I'm not sure it's going to work, is it possible to just call the public method "TicTac" where the GUI is recreated in a different class?

I've  been searching for so long but I can't find a way to do this?

```
    public void restart();
     TicTac restartok = new TicTac();
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank1);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.play);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank2);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.restart);
    restartok.add (restartok.row1);

    restartok.play.addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            restartok.boxes[x][y].addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious case is that the command is neither "Play" nor "Restart".

You could code this to quickly debug what is happening:

```
if (command.equals("Play")) {
    startPlaying();  
} else if (command.equals("Restart")) {
    restart();
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown command: " command);
}
```

Comment: Neither are throwing the IllegalArguementException, so I'm assuming it's my restart method which isn't executing, still clueless. But thanks for showing me that debug snippit.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `restart`? You have a `void restart();` but no definition of the method. If I am reading your code correctly you want to change

```
public void restart();
    TicTac restartok = new TicTac();
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank1);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.play);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank2);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.restart);
    restartok.add (restartok.row1);

    restartok.play.addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            restartok.boxes[x][y].addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
public void restart() {
    TicTac restartok = new TicTac();
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank1);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.play);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank2);
    restartok.row1.add(restartok.restart);
    restartok.add (restartok.row1);

    restartok.play.addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            restartok.boxes[x][y].addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this too, now it's calling, so my problem is most likely in my methods actual code, I'm assuming.